# Data is coming to view at the end not step by step; How to use Dispatcher to switch between UI thread and render thread?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

I am trying to build Status bar using a textbox using WPF and MVVM, status is coming but at a time in the end instead I want it to be coming step-by-step.

I have tried this code.
I also tried giving `Thread.Sleep(200);` in code but no significant changes were seen.
Creating a property for the Status in viewModel

```
private string myStatus;
public string MyStatus  
{
  get { return myStatus; }
  set
  {
    myStatus = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("MyStatus");
  }
}
```

and initializing it

```
public void LoadData()
{
  MyStatus = "";
  for(int i=0;i<list.Count();i++)
  {
    switch(list.ElementAt(i))
    {
      case -1:
       MyStatus = "Negative value\n";
       //Thread.Sleep(200);
       break;
      case 0: 
       MyStatus = "value is zero\n";
       //Thread.Sleep(200);break;
      case 1:
       MyStatus = "Positive value\n";
       //Thread.Sleep(200);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

and in the view binding it with property

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Name="tbMultiline" Text="{Binding MyStatus}" />
```

Textbox in getting populated, but at the end instead I want it to happen during each loop iteration.
UI is freezes for sometime and resume once the backend code completes. I searched about it, I got to know about dispatcher, can anyone tell me how to use dispatcher within MVVM pattern to switch between UI thread and render thread.

Comment: this is happening so fast that there is no chance to update the UI if you want to make this work you need to do it async with a pause between each call so the GUI can update

Comment: Is LoadData being called on the UI thread?  You might have to put it into a background thread and dispatch to the UI to have it update like you want.

Comment: But I can see those status in Console very well. I wrote Console.WriteLine("status") and it was coming one by one @Denis

Comment: I don't think so @KevinCook, I don't have idea about UI thread in WPF. I am quite a newbie here. I haven't used thread here so far.

Comment: what does "one by one mean"? there is no delay between they must 've come more or less immediately after each other

Comment: By "one by one" I mean, those status should come according to the progress made. In console I can see the output from Console.WriteLine but textbox is updated at the last. @DenisSchaf

Comment: that is because you are blocking the UI thread. You need to change that to a different thread

Comment: Can you please give me an example @DenisSchaf, because that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand your problem accurately.
You must change your xaml side code with that;

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Name="tbMultiline" Text="{Binding MyStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Berkay for your time. I want my textbox should display status in progressive manner. Each status should come one by one and unfortunately your code didn't helped.